# Drag an object in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag

I want to drag an object to a perticular place.In case I release that dragged object before I reach that particular area ,the object should come to its initial place where i start to drag. How it possible? Is there any specific motion for this?

```
void OnMouseDown()
 {

 drag = true;
//Debug.Log("haii ");
}
void OnMouseDrag()
{
if(drag)
{
    var pos =Input.mousePosition;
    pos.x =Mathf.Clamp(pos.x,0,Screen.width);
    pos.y =Mathf.Clamp(pos.y,0,Screen.height);
    if(zdist>0)
    {
    zdist=Vector3.Distance(Camera.main.transform.position,transform.position);
        pos.z=zdist;
        pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
        transform.position =pos;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnMouseUp()` for your case.
The idea is to check if the object is inside that particular area **WHEN** user release his click.

You can use `OnTriggerEnter()` to check if the object has reached that area.
If your object is still outside the area then return its original position.

Script for the object:

```
void OnMouseDown(){
    // save the original position for later use
    originalPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
    ....
}

void OnMouseUp(){
    if(drag){
        if(!areaReached)
            gameObject.transform.position = originalPosition;
        // i don't see you set drag to false in your code,
        // when user has released his click, he cannot drag anymore
        // set it to false
        drag = false;
    }
}
```

Script for the area:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider){
    // detect if the object enters the area
    if(collider.GameObject.name == "Your Object"){
        // get object's script and modify its variable
        ObjectScript obj = collider.GameObject.GetComponent<ObjectScript>();
        obj.areaReached = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider){
    // set it back to false if the object leaves the area before OnMouseUp
    if(collider.GameObject.name == "Your Object"){
        ObjectScript obj = collider.GameObject.GetComponent<ObjectScript>();
        obj.areaReached = false;
    }
}
```